# How to query TFS build server for properties inside process workflow items

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

We've set up a TFS server to perform builds for our project.

In the build process template DefaultTemplate.xaml we're trying to use the CopyDirectory component to copy files to the drop location (i.e., the server's output directory, where it places binaries).

It's got two fields; basically *from* and *to*, but how can we programmatically get the drop folder location without specifying it as a static string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the DefaultTemplate.xaml there is an example of this CopyDirectory activity being used:

```
<mtbwa:CopyDirectory
  Destination="[BuildDetail.DropLocation]" 
  DisplayName="Copy Files to Drop Location" Source="[BinariesDirectory]" />
```

BuildDetail.DropLocation is how you get the drop location programmatically.

Comment: Nice to see you on SO, Duat :)